# Podio Filter item method response missing files details

Tags: node.js, podio

In nodejs I am trying to filter podio data by using [FilterItems](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/filter-items-4496747) its working fine but its not giving files attributes. I can get the files count but I need uploaded files details. Here is my sample code

```
var Podio = require('podio-js').api;
var podio = new Podio({
                    authType: 'server',
                    clientId: 'XXXXX',
                    clientSecret:'*****************'
                });
podio.authenticateWithApp('XXXXX', 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYY', function(err) {
      podio.request('POST', '/item/app/XXXXX/filter', {
           "filters":  { "email":'sample@gmail.com'}
      }).then(function(responseData) {
              console.log(responseData);
      }).catch(function(e) {
              console.log(e);
      });
});
```

To solve this problem am doing one more call [Get Item](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-item-22360) by using Item-id (Which I have received from filter call).

Here my question is why filter method is not giving files details whether its bug in podio filter call or is there any specific reason. Please suggest better way too.

Note: In my scenario I should use only filter functionality;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get additional fields (including files) by bundling responses using fields parameter. It's described here: https://developers.podio.com/index/api

Sample:

```
// Include files when getting filtered items
/item/app/{app_id}/filter/?fields=items.fields(files)
```